# Can an IQueryable be reused with different values of the referenced local variables?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

The intention of the following code is to find an available ID.

My thinking when I wrote it was that each time `query.Any()` runs, then the query runs again with the newly incremented value in the local `id` variable.  This grew from my knowledge that `id` doesn't get evaluated until the query is executed.

From the results of my experiement, I can see this isn't how it works, and I'd like to know how you can re-write the code to accomplish its stated goal while keeping in the style of using LINQ to EF?

I know how to re-write in the trivial way - my goal is to better understand delayed execution of LINQ expressions and their execution context.

```
int id = 4700;
var query = from c in Advertisers
            where c.ID == id
            select c;
int loopCount = 0;
while(query.Any())
{
    if(++loopCount == 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Cannot find a safe id.");
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine ("Already a record with " + id);
    id++;
}
Console.WriteLine ("The available id is " + id);
```

Answer (score 0):

from the code above the problem is that id is updated but not your IQueryable object. You would need to change the value of id in the where clause of query. The easiest way I know of is to encapsulate the initial query and then change whatever I need.

For example:

```
    using (var context = new ModelContainer())
    {
        IQueryable<Advertiser> queryAdvertisers = 
            from c in context.Advertisers
            select c;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (queryAdvertisers.Where(a => a.ID == i).Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID:{0} already exists.", i);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID:{0} does not exist.", i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Normally I would refactor queryAdvertisers out into a method or class.